# select data from table with many clauses where 1

Tags: delphi

i dont know how to select from table with many condition in delphi it's my code

```
qr_catdegree.Close;
qr_catdegree.SQL.Clear;

qr_catdegree.SQL.Add('select * from cat_degreee where id_categ =+inttostr(id_categ)  and id_degree=+`inttostr(id_degree)' );
//qr_catdegree.SQL.Add(');

qr_catdegree.Open;
Indice_degree := qr_catdegree.FieldByName('Indice_degree').Asinteger;
edit15.text := inttostr(Indice_degree) ;`
```

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL and use parameters instead, which will avoid many difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused because you are trying to construct your Sql inside the call to SQL.Add.  this is obscuring the syntax errors in your attempt.

Try this instead

```
var
  S : String;
[...]
  qr_catdegree.Close; 
  qr_catdegree.SQL.Clear;

  S := 'select * from cat_degreee where id_categ = ' +  inttostr(id_categ);  
  //  do you REALLY mean 'degreee' and not 'degree'???

  S := S + ' and id_degree = ` + inttostr(id_degree); 

  qr_catdegree.SQL.Add(S);
```

Btw, you will have noticed that Ken White's comment recommends using parameters instead of what you are doing at the moment.  I agree with his recommendation for two reasons:

- Firstly, using parameters in a pre-prepared SQL query imposes less overhead on the server, because it only has to parse and compile the query once, rather than every time the query is executed.  With parameters, you can re-execute the query a number of times with different values for the parameters.
- Secondly, it is only a small step from including an expression like `+ IntToStr(SomeInteger)` in your SQL to including something like `+ Edit1.Text`, and you really should avoid **ever** doing that.  The reason is that it exposes your code to the risk of "SQL-Injection" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), because it gives a malicious user the opportunity to add addtional SQL commands in what they type into the TEdit.

Comment: that's very nice of u thnak u sir

Comment: I sincerely hope neither of you use this approach for string parameters...

Comment: @GerryColl:  Fair comment, and I don't, of course, but initially thought it would be a bit of a distraction to go into that in my answer.  But on second thoughts, I've added a bit of explanation of the point.

Comment: I have another problem when I choose data type mony but i need tow numbers Behind the comma not 4 numbers

Comment: These comments are not really a good place to discuss new issues.  I think you should post that as a new q, but make sure you use parameters in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As @KenWhite and @GerryCall said, use parameters;

```
  qr_catdegree.Close;
  qr_catdegree.SQL.Text := 'select * from cat_degreee where id_categ = :id_categ';
  qr_catdegree.SQL.Add('and id_degree = :id_degree');
  qr_catdegree.Parameters.ParamByName('id_categ').Value := id_categ;
  qr_catdegree.Parameters.ParamByName('id_degree').Value := id_degree;
  qr_catdegree.Open;
```